# GDI+ erroneous drawing under Windows explorer window

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi+, gdi, atl

I am using GDI* plus to do custom drawing, but I have a drawing error when my window gets drawn under a windows explorer window, it looks like this:
[image]
As u can see just under the explorer window.. the colors are weird.. the top right are buttons and the checkbox is also a button .. "Are you.." is a static control.. they are all inherited and implemented as custom controls.. when receiving WM_PAINT. I also use a buffered image in WM_PAINT.. anyway.. I can't explain this, any ideas? It works fine when not under windows explorer window, as u can see in the left site of the window.

The checkbox is a button control, use a `MSG_OCM_DRAWITEM(OnPaintImpl)` handler in which I get the DC as so:

```
LRESULT OnPaintImpl(UINT ctrlID, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS)
{
    ATLASSERT(GdiPlus::IsInitialized());

    OnPaintGdiPlus(lpDIS->hDC, lpDIS->rcItem, lpDIS->itemState);
    return S_OK;
}
```

and in my `OnPaintGdiPlus(HDC hDC, CRect rc, UINT nState)` I do this:

```
CMemoryDC dcMem(hDC, rc);
Graphics graphics(dcMem);
Rect rcClient = GdiPlus::GetRect(rc);
```

Everything else is just calling basic drawing functions from the graphics.

In the dialog I get `WM_PAINT` and handle it here:

```
LRESULT OnPaintImpl(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;     
    HDC hDC = BeginPaint(&ps);
    
    if (ps.rcPaint.right || ps.rcPaint.bottom)      // draw rect is defined
    {
        if (GdiPlus::IsInitialized())
            OnPaintGdiPlus(hDC, ps, GetClientRect(m_hWnd));
        else
            ::MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"Graphics mode not initialized properly!", L"Graphics", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }

    EndPaint(&ps);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Based on this hDC I create a Graphics object and paint using it.
Any other stuff I should add here?

Comment: It sucks to have to debug code from a screenshot.  Random guess: you are drawing to the desktop window instead of your own window.  GetWindowDC(NULL) does that.

Comment: I know.. I 'm sorry but I don't know what it would be of interest because it's too much code for it.. thank you for your question.. I'll edit to include that information..

Comment: I never use GetWindowDC(NULL)

Comment: @HansPassant do you have any ideas on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810755/delete-shell-forlder-contents-using-ifileoperation