# Windows message Loop confusion

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, atl, wtl

I have a GUI window in WTL that runs inside a thread inside a CMessageLoop instance which has been added to the application instance and runs. Now, inside a button handler within the main GUI I create a new window. Once I click that button and create the window and try to post the quit message to the main GUI loop. The code:

Main window, has its own thread:

```
    CMessageLoop theLoop;
    _MyppModule.AddMessageLoop(&theLoop);
    if(m_pMyDlg == NULL) {
        m_pMyDlg = new CMyDlg();
        if(!IsWindow(*m_pMyDlg))
        {
            m_pMyDlg->Create(NULL);
            m_pMyDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            nRet = theLoop.Run();
            _MyppModule.RemoveMessageLoop();
        }
    }
```

Button handler & child window creation:

```
LRESULT CMyDlg::OnButtonClicked(WORD wNotifyCode, WORD wID, HWND hWndCtl, BOOL& bHandled)
{

     ChildWindowDlg childDlg;
     childDlg.Create(m_hWnd);

     childDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

     CMessageLoop _loop;
     );

     _loop.Run();
     ::DestroyWindow(childDlg);

     return S_OK;
}
```

Now, if I click the Close button in my MyDlg window the button's handler will get called, inside it I do `::PostQuitMessage` but that never reaches  the theLoop messageloop from the first code snippet. 
This happens after I exit the second loop, so _loop gets destroyed  and the child dialog is destroyed.
What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code snippet is totally unnatural. If your goal is to have a window popped up, then closed and and then you want to complete execution of your button click handler, then modal dialog is what you need:

```
LRESULT CMyDlg::OnButtonClicked(WORD wNotifyCode, WORD wID, HWND hWndCtl, 
                                BOOL& bHandled)
{
     ChildWindowDlg childDlg; // Add constructor parameters if needed
     // Additional initlaization calls might go here
     const INT_PTR nResult = childDlg.DoModal(m_hWnd); // DoModal handles it all
     if(nResult == IDOK) { ... } // Hey's we even have result coming from `EndDialog`
     return 0; // No S_OK here
}
```

No message loops, no `PostQuitMessage`, no separate window creation/destruction calls needed. This is what modal dialogs are for.

---

If you don't want to block "calling" window, and the idea is to have both master and slave windows running side by side (or, one is a part of another, anyway both to be responsive at the same time), then you don't want to block your message handler. The handler will create window and set it up (`.Create`, `.ShowWindow`) and then exit from `OnButtonClicked` function.

Both windows are created, both are alive and have their message sent to them by top level message loop. This is the correct approach, you don't normally need more than one message loop per thread. Sometimes it might make sense for specific operations, but this is really rare. Windows are passive instances. They respond to messages with their message handlers. A thread message loop serves all thread windows, because what it does is `DispatchMessage` API call, which in turn looks for target window, takes its `WndProc` and calls it handing message details in.

Comment: I want that second window to be like a frame in my main dlg

Comment: So I'd like to be able to call other controls from the main GUI as well.. I don't want the child to block the parent

Comment: and now I still have one problem.. what if the WM_QUIT message comes from the parent when the child is active? it will end the child loop, destroy the windows.. but the main window loop will still be active.

Comment: The problem presented applies in the way I did it, do you have any better ideas?

Comment: I could get around this problem if I would run the child dialog inside the main loop, but that would mean destroying and recreating the child window dinamically in that button handler, I need to do so because I might need it in a different language... Is this a good approach?

Comment: Without blocking... you don't need second message loop. Either way second loop is incorrect. You need `Create` + `ShowWindow` and leave the handler (function). The window will be created and will be served off the save message loop as the owning window.

Comment: any ideas on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803783/gdi-erroneous-drawing-under-windows-explorer-window

Comment: I don't think you posted relevant code there, so you don't have relevant feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You have two message loops here, the child's one is nested. On the other hand, the message queue is one per thread, and is pumped by the most inner message loop (with `GetMessage`). So, `WM_QUIT` message gets retrieved by the inner message loop inside `CMyDlg::OnButtonClicked`.

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to mention: after I close the child dialog and exit the handler function, I'll edit right away.

Comment: How do you exit the second loop, do you call  `PostQuitMessage` twice? Show more code.

Comment: Man.... I wasn't calling PostQuitMessage from the childDialog.. iwas just hiding it.. my bad!